# Delete recursively a LDAP subtree with python

Tags: python, recursion, ldap, python-ldap

Using [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/), I want to delete an entire subtree of my LDAP tree.

I came up with :

```
def ldap_recursive_delete_s(con, base_dn):
    search = con.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE)
    delete_list = [dn for dn, _ in search]
    delete_list.reverse()

    for dn in delete_list:
        con.delete_s(dn)
```

I was wondering if there is any kind of "recursive" option like with the `ldaprm` CLI tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think there is any option like that.

you will have to iterate and delete entries.
One gotcha that i would like to mention is you can't delete an OU with objects under it, unless you have a different setting in AD.

Comment: Sadly, that's the answer I came to… For the unability to delet non-empty OU, It's true, even in plain LDAP (not using AD but openldap).

Answer (score 5):

For those who might stumble on this question later, here's a quick and dirty piece I wrote for myself (Essentially what @navendu says):

```
def recursive_delete(conn, base_dn):
    search = conn.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL)

    for dn, _ in search:
        recursive_delete(conn, dn)

    print "Deleting: ", base_dn
    conn.delete_s(base_dn)
```

Comment: Short and simple!  Brilliant!